# How to iterate over urlparse.urlsplit() result Python

Tags: python, url, urllib

Let's say I have this code:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> url = "http://google.com"
>>> s = urlparse.urlsplit(url)
>>> print s
SplitResult(scheme='http', netloc='google.com', path='', query='', fragment='')
>>> print 'scheme ',s.scheme    
scheme  http
>>> print 'netloc ',s.netloc
netloc  google.com
```

As you can see, I can iterate over the items manually, but how can I do this automatically? I want to do something like this:

```
# This doesn't work:
for k,v in s.items():
    print '%s : %s'%(k,v)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the internal `_asdict` method:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> url = "http://google.com"
>>> s = urlparse.urlsplit(url)
>>> s
SplitResult(scheme='http', netloc='google.com', path='', query='', fragment='')
>>> s._asdict()
OrderedDict([('scheme', 'http'), ('netloc', 'google.com'), ('path', ''), ('query', ''), ('fragment', '')])
>>> d = s._asdict()
>>> for k,v in d.items():
...     print k, repr(v)
... 
scheme 'http'
netloc 'google.com'
path ''
query ''
fragment ''
```

To clarify a point raised in the comments, despite the prefix `_`, which usually indicates a method not part of a public interface, the method is a public one.  It's given the prefix to avoid name conflicts, as the `namedtuple` docs explain [[link]](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/collections.html?highlight=namedtuple#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields):

> To prevent conflicts with field names, the method and attribute names
>   start with an underscore.

And in Python 3, this is much easier due to an implementation change:

```
>>> vars(urllib.parse.urlsplit("http://www.google.ca"))
OrderedDict([('scheme', 'http'), ('netloc', 'www.google.ca'), ('path', ''), ('query', ''), ('fragment', '')])
```

Comment: Is the `_asdict()` method documented anywhere? I didn't see it.

Comment: @Matt http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections#collections.somenamedtuple._asdict

Comment: I found it by looking at `help(s)`, where `s` is the `SplitResult` object.

Comment: @DSM Ahh, okay. I wasn't aware that `SplitResult` was a namedtuple. The documentation I was reading about urlparse just said it was a tuple.

Comment: Note that methods with a leading underscore are meant to be internal and are not considered part of the public interface. Use them carefully and expect them to change in the future.

Comment: @SeanPerry: usually, but here the motivation is a little different.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> url = "http://google.com"
>>> s = urlparse.urlsplit(url)
>>> scheme, netloc, path, query, fragment = s
>>> scheme
'http'
>>> netloc
'google.com'
>>> path
''
>>> query
''
>>> fragment
''
```

As shown above the SplitResult is really a fancy tuple so you can use standard assignment as well.

```
>>> scheme, netloc, _, _, _ = s # I only want the scheme and netloc
```

Enjoy.